# Java: Key(Certificate) had its own password aside from the Keystore's password

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore, change-password

Is it feasible for the Key(Certificate) which is stored to the Keystore to have their own password?

What will happen to the integrity of the keys and their passwords if the Keystore's password is changed or if we changed the password of each key(certificate) to make it unique for security reasons?

I attached a table to make it clear.

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the password for the private key can be different to the keystores password.

The integrity is not touched by using different passwords for the key and the keystore.

If you have different keys in your keystore then the integrity is slightly lowered by having the same password for the key(s) and the keystore.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can we achieve this programmatically? Like changing the password of the keystore thru code and the keys are still there along with their passwords? Because so far, what I have read is that we can only change the password thru overwriting the keystore using the same name but with different password, which I believe might erase the keys in the overridden keystore.

Comment: Please ask a new question forthis and add your code to that question.